# XPath Exclude nodes based on attributes of multiple other nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to write XPath against the XML below that will get me all nodes in the list with @id='ResponseActionList' for a specific @rsp_cd where the @act_cd does not exist in the list with @id='ActExcludeList'

```
<resp-env>
   <cmd-resp>
      <static>
         <list id="ResponseActionList">
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A1" act_tx="A1 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A2" act_tx="A2 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A4" act_tx="A4 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A5" act_tx="A5 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A6" act_tx="A6 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R1" act_cd="A7" act_tx="A7 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A1" act_tx="A1 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A2" act_tx="A2 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A3" act_tx="A3 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A4" act_tx="A4 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A5" act_tx="A5 Text"/>
            <listRow rsp_cd="R2" act_cd="A6" act_tx="A6 Text"/>
         </list>
         <list id="ActExcludeList">
            <listRow act_cd="A2"/>
            <listRow act_cd="A3"/>
         </list>
      </static>
   </cmd-resp>
</resp-env>
```

I can easily get all the nodes containing the appropriate @rsp_cd with this:

```
//static/list[@id='ResponseActionList']/listRow[@rsp_cd='R2']
```

And I can exclude nodes for a particular @act_cd with this:

```
//static/list[@id='ResponseActionList']/listRow[@rsp_cd='R2' and @act_cd!='A2']
```

What I want is to exclude all nodes from the first expression above where the @act_cd attribute is not in the results of this expression:

```
//static/list[@id='ActExcludeList']/listRow/@act_cd
```

I tried something like this, which I didn't expect to work, and I'm not sure what to try next:

```
//static/list[@id='ResponseActionList']/listRow[@rsp_cd='R2' and not(contains(//static/list[@id='ActExcludeList']/listRow/@act_cd,@act_cd))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains` function is used to find substrings in other strings, not values in a node set. The operator you're looking for is `=`, which is existentially quantified in XPath - the expression `a = b` where `a` and/or `b` are node sets will succeed if *any* node in the set `a` matches *any* in `b`.

```
//static/list[@id='ResponseActionList']/listRow[@rsp_cd='R2' and
    not(@act_cd = //static/list[@id='ActExcludeList']/listRow/@act_cd)]
```

Comment: Perfect. I figured this would be something easy. Thanks!